# pd.read_csv: delimiter = '\t' and header=None not compatible

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this line of code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('some_file.txt',engine ='python', 
                  delimiter = '\t', header=None, encoding="utf-16")
```

I'm using those txt files quiet often in my lab, one of our machines gives them as output.
If I only use the delimiter I get a nice table, but with the first element as header for everything. If I only use header = None I get rid of the header, but have a bunch of \t everywhere. If I try to use both commands, I get this error:

```
ParserError: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 23
```

When removing enigne = 'python' I get a similar error.
(also tried seperator and a bunch of other things)

Help would be very much appreciated!

Edit: As requested that's how the file looks like:

```
##BLOCKS= 1
Plate:  Plate1  1.3 PlateFormat Endpoint    Absorbance  Raw FALSE   1                       1   562     1   12  96  1   8       
    Temperature(¡C) 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12      
    26.5    0.8368  0.5211  0.321   0.2707  0.2124  0.1768  0.1694  0.1635  0.1659  0.1029  0.1032  0.104       
        0.7142  0.4866  0.2968  0.252   0.2111  0.1737  0.1633  0.162   0.1599  0.1009  0.1007  0.1025      
        0.3499  0.2119  0.2799  0.2097  0.3114  0.3393  0.2544  0.2965  0.2392  0.3063  0.3093  0.2655      
        0.305   0.2068  0.2573  0.2008  0.287   0.2765  0.2373  0.2703  0.2357  0.2865  0.2926  0.263       
        0.2922  0.3456  0.1964  0.2667  0.3022  0.2596  0.2256  0.2387  0.2498  0.2936  0.2396  0.3411      
        0.3018  0.349   0.2069  0.272   0.2926  0.2444  0.2141  0.2348  0.2486  0.2678  0.2346  0.2944      
        0.2965  0.3505  0.2427  0.3322  0.1873  0.2286  0.3758  0.208   0.3023  0.3573  0.3141  0.2658      
        0.2956  0.3155  0.2514  0.2929  0.1985  0.2379  0.1898  0.2101  0.3211  0.3558  0.3121  0.2567      

~End
Original Filename: 20220725_Benedikt_DEF; Date Last Saved: 7/25/2022 2:31:30 PM
```

That's how it looks like when I read it without pandas:

['##BLOCKS= 1\n', 'Plate:\tPlate1\t1.3\tPlateFormat\tEndpoint\tAbsorbance\tRaw\tFALSE\t1\t\t\t\t\t\t1\t562 \t1\t12\t96\t1\t8\t\t\n', '\tTemperature(¡C)\t1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8\t9\t10\t11\t12\t\t\n', '\t26.5\t0.8368\t0.5211\t0.321\t0.2707\t0.2124\t0.1768\t0.1694\t0.1635\t0.1659\t0.1029\t0.1032\t0.104\t\t\n', '\t\t0.7142\t0.4866\t0.2968\t0.252\t0.2111\t0.1737\t0.1633\t0.162\t0.1599\t0.1009\t0.1007\t0.1025\t\t\n', '\t\t0.3499\t0.2119\t0.2799\t0.2097\t0.3114\t0.3393\t0.2544\t0.2965\t0.2392\t0.3063\t0.3093\t0.2655\t\t\n', '\t\t0.305\t0.2068\t0.2573\t0.2008\t0.287\t0.2765\t0.2373\t0.2703\t0.2357\t0.2865\t0.2926\t0.263\t\t\n', '\t\t0.2922\t0.3456\t0.1964\t0.2667\t0.3022\t0.2596\t0.2256\t0.2387\t0.2498\t0.2936\t0.2396\t0.3411\t\t\n', '\t\t0.3018\t0.349\t0.2069\t0.272\t0.2926\t0.2444\t0.2141\t0.2348\t0.2486\t0.2678\t0.2346\t0.2944\t\t\n', '\t\t0.2965\t0.3505\t0.2427\t0.3322\t0.1873\t0.2286\t0.3758\t0.208\t0.3023\t0.3573\t0.3141\t0.2658\t\t\n', '\t\t0.2956\t0.3155\t0.2514\t0.2929\t0.1985\t0.2379\t0.1898\t0.2101\t0.3211\t0.3558\t0.3121\t0.2567\t\t\n', '\n', '~End\n', 'Original Filename: some_file; Date Last Saved: 7/25/2022 2:31:30 PM\n']

When I use just use the pd.read_csv(file, encoding =''utf-16')

I get this:

[image]

It' basically a file that is stating the wavelength absorbance from a sample plate with 8 rows and 12 columns (96 samples).

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverFlow, can you please add the first 5 lines of your `txt` file in a new edit ?

Comment: What if you try : `df = pd.read_csv('some_file.txt')`

Comment: Try `delim_whitespace=True` instead of `delimiter = '\t'`. If that doesn't work you will need to include a minimal example of the csv - a few rows and columns.

Comment: you could try using `sep='\t'` instead of delimiter and see if that helps.

Comment: I added all the other infos, also tried the delim_whitespace=True command. I get this error: ParserError: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 16. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

Comment: You don't have a plain csv file - it has more structure. At minimum you need to use the `skiprows` parameter and the maybe `skipfooter` with `.read_csv`. Did you read [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-read-csv-table)?

Comment: @wwii Yes, I read the documentation and I tried skiprows. Same error, it is not compatible with the delimeter command. I don't know whether this error is due to my inexperience as coder or if those files are just messy. It is possible to get the data in another format (.xlsx) but we still have a huge chunk of data with the current format. So if there's an elegant solution for this That'd be great, otherwise I find a way around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all the files have the same structure and you only want the data; skip the first four rows, don't use the last three rows, whitespace delimiter, no header, python engine.

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(csv,skiprows=4,skipfooter=3,header=None,delim_whitespace=True,engine='python')
>>> df
       0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11
0  0.7142  0.4866  0.2968  0.2520  0.2111  0.1737  0.1633  0.1620  0.1599  0.1009  0.1007  0.1025
1  0.3499  0.2119  0.2799  0.2097  0.3114  0.3393  0.2544  0.2965  0.2392  0.3063  0.3093  0.2655
2  0.3050  0.2068  0.2573  0.2008  0.2870  0.2765  0.2373  0.2703  0.2357  0.2865  0.2926  0.2630
3  0.2922  0.3456  0.1964  0.2667  0.3022  0.2596  0.2256  0.2387  0.2498  0.2936  0.2396  0.3411
4  0.3018  0.3490  0.2069  0.2720  0.2926  0.2444  0.2141  0.2348  0.2486  0.2678  0.2346  0.2944
5  0.2965  0.3505  0.2427  0.3322  0.1873  0.2286  0.3758  0.2080  0.3023  0.3573  0.3141  0.2658
6  0.2956  0.3155  0.2514  0.2929  0.1985  0.2379  0.1898  0.2101  0.3211  0.3558  0.3121  0.2567
>>>
```